# Before Interview Question: Gifts or challenges for the hiring manager?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I had to submit a form about my preferences of the upcoming interview. One of the question, which I do not understand was:

*For your interview, do you have any gifts or challenges that the hiring manager should be aware of?*

<sub>*If yes, please explain any needed accommodations.*</sub>

<kbd>Your Answer ....</kbd>

Could please someone enlighten me on what does this question mean or give some examples of gifts/challenges.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In less politically correct times, they would have asked if you have any disabilities that the company needs to prepare for. For example, do you need a ramp for a wheelchair, are you blind or deaf, do you have any other problems that you need to attend to. Maybe you are a diabetic and *need* to get a punctual lunch. Maybe it's not the smartest move to invite the guy with a broken leg to an interview the same day that the yearly elevator maintenance is happening. Those things.

Obviously now it's "gifts" and "challenges". It's still asking if you have special needs the company needs to know about.

Comment: Is "gifts and challenges" a common phrase for "special needs" elsewhere in the world (I'm an ignorant American).

Comment: Your answer made it clear to me. I'm not a native English speaker, and when I read the OP's question, for a second I thought he was asked whether he intended to bribe the hiring manager...

Comment: "It's still asking if you have special needs the company needs to know about."  Needs in terms of conducting the interview, or in terms of having you as an employee in the workplace?

Comment: @DJohnM The question said "For your interview,", so I guess it's for the interview. i cannot tell what the people do with the information they gain from the interview though.

Comment: Now I understand `challenges` part. But what is a `gift` part here?

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Hypercorrectness. First the terms were disabled/disadvantaged (negative), then it became " differently abled" / " challenges" (neither positive nor negative", and now "gifts" tries to spin a disability as an advantage. Of course, if wheelchairs were _that_ good, everyone would be using them.